# Python np.lognormal gives infinite results for big average and St Dev

Tags: python, mean, standard-deviation, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to draw the lognormal distribution for my data. using the following code :

```
mu, sigma = 136519., 50405. # mean and standard deviation

hs = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000) #mean, s dev , Size

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(hs, 100, normed=True) 

x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 10000)

pdf = (math.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)))


plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.axis('tight')
```

As you can see, my maean and sigma are big values, it creates the problem that hs goes to infinity that gives error .

while if I put something like mu =3 and sigma =1, it works, any suggestions for big numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply generate normal variables $x_i\sim N(136519, 50405^2)$. Numpy should be able to handle this.

Then take exponentials: $e^{x_i}$. These are on the order of $e^{150,000}$. Numpy will likely *not* be able to handle this. If you really need numbers on this scale, look into [dedicated libraries for working with big floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538551/452096).

[The lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with log-mean $\mu$ and log-SD $\sigma$ has an expected value $e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$. For the values you have, this is about as close to infinity as you are likely to get, and actual realizations will of course be much larger.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately I'm new and can't give you positive vote

Comment: Dear Stephan, I am actually trying to replicate this graph in Python, that can be producced ,maybe without problems, in MINITAB, so at this point,  I have a bit of doubt, whether my work in python would get to the point to give the same results, because most of the times I will be working with big numbers

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in Python. If you are interested in plotting large numbers in Python, that would be off-topic here. [These links may be helpful.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1090/1352)

Comment: You are right Stephan, I have been asking my statistics questions on Stackoverflow, though, regarding the fact that this is a mixed topic, there are few people that would be interested to answer my questions there , still I apperciate your answer

Comment: Creating a given type of plot with large numbers should be perfectly on-topic at SO. It doesn't matter whether these numbers come from a statistical model. Just make sure you include a Minimum Working Example in your question.